# Physical CPU in AIX

Tags: aix

Can someone let me know Why the number of physical CPU's is greater than the number of virtual CPU's in AIX.

***Online Virtual CPUs                        : 8,
Active Physical CPUs in system             : 48,
Desired Virtual CPUs                       : 8***

```
Partition Number                           : 30
Type                                       : Shared-SMT-4
Mode                                       : Uncapped
Entitled Capacity                          : 0.80
Partition Group-ID                         : 32798
Shared Pool ID                             : 0
**Online Virtual CPUs                        : 8**
Maximum Virtual CPUs                       : 160
Minimum Virtual CPUs                       : 1
Online Memory                              : 84992 MB
Maximum Memory                             : 127488 MB
Minimum Memory                             : 256 MB
Variable Capacity Weight                   : 128
Minimum Capacity                           : 0.10
Maximum Capacity                           : 16.00
Capacity Increment                         : 0.01
Maximum Physical CPUs in system            : 48
**Active Physical CPUs in system             : 48**
Active CPUs in Pool                        : 48
Shared Physical CPUs in system             : 48
Maximum Capacity of Pool                   : 4800
Entitled Capacity of Pool                  : 1190
Unallocated Capacity                       : 0.00
Physical CPU Percentage                    : 10.00%
Unallocated Weight                         : 0
Memory Mode                                : Dedicated
Total I/O Memory Entitlement               : -
Variable Memory Capacity Weight            : -
Memory Pool ID                             : -
Physical Memory in the Pool                : -
Hypervisor Page Size                       : -
Unallocated Variable Memory Capacity Weight: -
Unallocated I/O Memory entitlement         : -
Memory Group ID of LPAR                    : -
**Desired Virtual CPUs                       : 8**
Desired Memory                             : 84992 MB
Desired Variable Capacity Weight           : 128
Desired Capacity                           : 0.80
Target Memory Expansion Factor             : -
Target Memory Expansion Size               : -
Power Saving Mode                          : Disabled
Sub Processor Mode                         : -
```

Comment: I would think _partition_ means 'part of' or 'not the whole'.

Answer (score 0):

Your "Entitled Capacity" is 0.8. And the each fraction of a single processor equals 0.1 of one physical processor. So you get 8 virtual processors. [Here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1024788) you can get more information about this:

> **What is the capacity entitlement?**
>
> Physical processors are presented to a logical partition's operating
>   systems as virtual processors. Physical processors are virtualized
>   into portions or fractions. Each fraction of a single processor equals
>   0.1 of one processor. There is an additional fraction of 0.01 The number of cores assigned to a partition is represented by the Capacity
>   Entitlement. To display the assigned capacity entitlement for a shared
>   partition use the command # lparstat|awk -F "ent=" '/ent\=/ {print
>   $NF}' The output will be the number of processorsthis partition is
>   entitled to use. This is the upper threshold the partition can have
>   from the processor pool (Capped mode). The partition can use more than
>   the assigned capacity entitlement (Uncapped mode). Capped and uncapped
>   modes details will be illustrated later in this document. The number
>   of virtual processors and processing units that are assigned to a
>   partition can be changed through the HMC.
>
> **Capacity Entitlement considerations:**
>
> Capacity entitlement should be correctly configured for normal
>   production operation and to cover workload during peak time. Having
>   enough capacity entitlement is important so as not to impact operating
>   system performance and processor affinity. Running over entitled
>   capacity can cause bad affinity and noticeable performance degradation
>   affecting business operation.
>
> **Virtual Processors:**
>
> A virtual processor is a representation of a physical processor core
>   to the operating system of a partition that uses shared processors. It
>   is the number of physical processors that the logical partition can
>   spread out across. It represents the upper threshold for the number of
>   physical processors that can be used. We recommend not to increase the
>   ratio between the virtual processors to entitled capacity to more than
>   1.6 Each partition has its own assigned virtual processors. The partition will work only on the virtual processors needed for its
>   workload. The unneeded virtual processors assigned to a partition will
>   fold away using processor folding feature. To display the current
>   assigned virtual processors use the command # lparstat -i | grep -i
>   "Desired Virtual CPUs" Using an HMC, you can change the number of
>   virtual processors and processing units that are assigned to the
>   partition.

Answer (score 0):

The given Physical CPU is the number of Physical CPUs installed on the power machine where this lpar is hosted. The Virtual CPU is the allocated Virtual CPU to this particular LPAR.

Also Desired Virtual CPU and Online Virtual CPU are the same thing.